# Linux: how to copy a file with a new name into the same directory?

Tags: linux

I have a file under `/usr/share/applications/eclipse.desktop` and I want to copy and rename it, creating a new file `/usr/share/applications/eclipse_clean.desktop`.

What is the simplest way to do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
cp /usr/share/applications/eclipse.desktop /usr/share/applications/eclipse_clean.desktop
```

Answer (score 2):

```
cp /usr/share/applications/eclipse.desktop  /usr/share/applications/eclipse_clean.desktop
```

cp--->For copy first argument provide to cp should be source and second argument should be destination

Answer (score 1):

```
cp  /usr/share/application/eclipse{,_clean}.desktop
```

**EDIT**: as pointed out in comments, this works under bash, but might not work under other shells

Comment: Could you please write a `cp` properly? This will not work in all shells.